# CSS text positioning - circle backround on a tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop, positioning

I have created a navigation that is a circle of circles, I need to get the text for each link into the center, I can do this with the line height if there is only one word but most of them have more then one word.

How can I get this to work?

SAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/elogicmedia/nVPYQ/12/

An image to show what I am talking about. See the text is all at the top of each link.

[image]

MY CSS CODE

```
nav {
    position: relative;
top: 200px;
left: 200px;
    font-family: helvetica, arial;
}
li {
list-style: none;
}
a {
position: absolute;
text-decoration: none;
width:98px;
height:98px;
border-radius:50%;
line-height:1.5em;
text-align:center;
    font-family: helvetica, arial;
    background-color: #C0D9D9;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
}
a:hover {
   color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not *too* hard to get working with JS.  You can calculate the height of each `a` and the height of the text itself by wrapping it in a span.  Use `position: relative` on the span, and set `top` to the appropriate middle point based on the calculation.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/nVPYQ/13/

Comment: Nice, but sucks on positioning.